# Relative Layout fill_parent issue

Tags: java, android, xml, android-relativelayout, fill-parent

First of all, I am new to Android development so this might be a simple issue but I really can't get it working.

I have the following layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
              android:orientation="vertical" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:weightSum="1">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/navigationBarFrameLayout" 
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="44dp">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/navigationBar"
                   android:src="@drawable/navigationbar"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                   android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
        <TextView android:text="TextView"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                  android:id="@+id/navigationBarTitle" 
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                  android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                  android:textColor="#000" 
                  android:textSize="24sp" 
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:shadowColor="#fff"
                  android:shadowDy="-1" 
                  android:shadowDx="0"
                  android:shadowRadius="1"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:id="@+id/DayPager"
             android:layout_height="82dp">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">
        <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/ScheduleScrollView" 
                                  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                  android:fadingEdge="none" 
                                  android:layout_above="@+id/tabBarFrameLayout"
                                  android:scrollbars="none" 
                                  android:background="#00ff00">
            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/ScheduleRelativeLayout" 
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                      android:id="@+id/ScheduleTimelineRelativeLayout">
                            </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                                      android:id="@+id/ScheduleConcertsRelativeLayout"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/ScheduleTimelineRelativeLayout"
                                            android:background="#ff0000" 
                                            android:layout_weight="1">
                           </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/tabBarFrameLayout" 
                     android:layout_height="49dp"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
                     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
                       android:src="@drawable/tabbar" 
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                       android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
        </FrameLayout>     
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What you see is that I have a horizontal scrollview (`ScheduleScrollView`) which has two relative layouts. The upper one contains a timeline (`ScheduleTimelineRelativeLayout`) while the lower one (`ScheduleConcertsRelativeLayout`) will contain some buttons created programmatically. The horizontal scrollview is as wide as the timeline. I would like the lower relative layout to fill it's parent, meaning that it should be as wide as the horizontal scrollview but this doesn't work.

I have searched this forum trying to find an answer to my question. Some suggests using `android:layout_width="match_parent"` but when doing so, I will get the following error:

> Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value
>   'match_parent')

Others suggests setting `android:layout_weight="1"` but this changes nothing (and the setting is not available in my autocomplete so it seems that it doesn't exist)

The screenshot below shows my issue. The green part is the background color of my horizontal scrollview. This should not be visible. Instead the lower red part should go to the edge.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Setting the width and height of `ScheduleConcertsRelativeLayout` programatically after the layout has been laid is working.

```
RelativeLayout timeline = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ScheduleTimelineRelativeLayout);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(timeline.getWidth(), scheduleConcertsRelativeLayout.getHeight());
params.setMargins(0, timeline.getHeight(), 0, 0);
scheduleConcertsRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the width and height of ScheduleConcertsRelativeLayout programatically after the layout has been laid is working.

```
RelativeLayout timeline = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ScheduleTimelineRelativeLayout);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(timeline.getWidth(), scheduleConcertsRelativeLayout.getHeight());
params.setMargins(0, timeline.getHeight(), 0, 0);
scheduleConcertsRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably missing something here, but did you try to change:

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/ScheduleScrollView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" ... \>
```

to

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/ScheduleScrollView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" ... \>
```

Comment: Yes, that gives me the same. But it's not really the scrollview which is the problem. It's the bottom relative layout in the scroll view which is the problem.

Comment: Yep but your RelativeLayout parent is this HorizontalScrollView, hence the remark. Anyways, I'm as stuck as you here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` on `ScheduleRelativeLayout`?

Comment: On the horizontal scrollview? Yes, that gives me the same. But it's not really the scrollview which is the problem. It's the bottom relative layout in the scroll view which is the problem.

Comment: No, in `ScheduleRelativeLayout` ("horizontal scrollview" already extends to full width)

Comment: Please also try `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` on `ScheduleRelativeLayout`. Do both changes at the same time.

Comment: That makes the scrollview begin on the middle, show the last half of it and then show blank space the rest half.

Comment: One last try: `android:layout_gravity="RIGHT"` on `ScheduleRelativeLayout`, if this doesn't work then I don't know :(

Comment: That's the same, sadly. Though, I have found out that if I update the width and height of my `ScheduleConcertsRelativeLayout` after the layout has been laid, it is working. Check the original post.